# how to put a new line/carriage return in file created by a bash script

Tags: linux, bash

In my bash script I have:

```
echo -e '#!/bin/sh /n GIT_WORK_TREE=/home/realopti/domains/$name git checkout -f' >> ~/domains/$name.git/hooks/post-receive
```

This generates:

```
#!/bin/sh /n GIT_WORK_TREE=/home/realopti/domains/john git checkout -f
```

in my post-receive file.

I'd like the file to look like:

```
#!/bin/sh
GIT_WORK_TREE=/home/realopti/domains/john git checkout -f
```

How can I make this happen.

Thank you,

Bill

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That should be `\n`, not `/n`.  You may also want to remove the space after it, but it doesn't matter.

Answer (score 2):

`cat` is more appropriate than `echo` for this:

```
cat << \EOF > ~/domains/$name.git/hooks/post-receive
#!/bin/sh
GIT_WORK_TREE=/home/realopti/domains/john git checkout -f
EOF
```

but for this particular situation it's probably better to use a template.  Put the content you want in `$HOME/template-dir/hooks/post-receive` and set `GIT_TEMPLATE_DIR=$HOME/template-dir` in the environment of the shell with which you are creating your git repository.  (That is, make the assignment in you startup files.)